# why my cli give an error when I pushing my app?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I'm deploying an app on Heroku.

1. I have created a heroku account
2. I have installed heroku CLI
3. I have created a requirements.txt file
4. I have specified the Python Runtime.
5. I have modified settings.py for Heroku
6. I have made the procfile to start processes.
7. I'm using git to track the project's files.
8. I have done the committing the project.

And when I want to do the pushing to heroku with the command `git push heroku master` I have this error in the terminal:

```
error: src refsoec master: no concuerda con ninguno
error: falló el push de algunas referencias a 'https://git.heroku.com/quiet-wildwood-34710.git'
```

Someone knows the solution?
Thanks

Comment: We can't tell you because the error is literally not in english

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+master

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue could be due to git remote origins.
Rater than Heroku git, use Github repository to publish your app on Heroku.
You can find this option under the deploy section of your Heroku app. Just connect the Github repository and enable automatic deploys.
You are just done for now and in the future, if you update your Github repository, Heroku will make automatic deploys.